# correcting permissions on Mac after Mountain Lion install

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

Upgrading to Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard has affected a lot of the software I use. While trying to update and install some Ruby gems on my system as well as other software (using Homebrew), I got this error message

```
Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
```

Does anyone know how I can change ownership and permissions of /usr/local back to my user account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Homebrew tells you what to do:

> You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
>   back to your user account.

For that we'll use `chown` and (recursively) set your user as the owner for `/usr/local`:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

This GitHub Gist does the same and a little more, which may or may not be required to get a fully working Homebrew again: [Fix permissions on /usr/local for Homebrew](https://gist.github.com/768518)